# iOS Twitter share button confusion

Tags: ios, twitter, uibutton

I wanted to implement Twitter share button that when the user clicks on the Twitter Button and the twitter message pops up, then they click POST and that post is sent to the user's twitter page.

I implemented social framework

```
-(IBAction)Twitter:(id)sender{

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
      SLComposeViewController *TWITTER = [SLComposeViewController
                                composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

     [TWITTER addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://twitter.com/@TweetAccount"]];  //<-- Do I even need this line?

     [self presentViewController:TWITTER animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
 }
```

As long as I'm signed into twitter through my iOS device and when I click on the Twitter button, the POST is sent to the @TweetAccount URL. However, when the user is signed into their Twitter account on their device and click on the twitter button in my app, will their POST also go to my @TweetAccount or will it go to their own account? (This is the part i'm confused on)

If I accidentally made it go to my account, how do I make the POST go to their account?